# What replaced AsyncEmitter in rxjava 2?

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to migrate a Reactive project from rxjava 1 to version 2. I was using an AsyncEmitter to attach to an existing feed, by specifiying a BackpressureMode. However I am not finding a comparable way to do this in rxjava2. What replaced AsyncEmitter in rxjava 2? I see there are a number of emitter implementations, but none accept a BackPressureStrategy.

I tried

```
FlowableCreate flowableCreate = 
         new FlowableCreate(source, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
flowableCreate.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

and it compiles fine, but execution fails right away with:

Error:(123, 23) java: cannot access org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
  class file for org.reactivestreams.Subscriber not found. Huh?

Comment: AFAIK, in RxJava 2 you have Flowable that supports backpressure and Observable which does not. Perhaps you want create an Observable first and then switch to a Flowable?

Comment: Tried that, but weird compilation errors.

Comment: Looks like an IntelliJ bug. This works fine on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.x, the method you are looking for is `Flowable.create()`.

You get the `cannot access org.reactivestreams.Subscriber` likely because you don't use 2.0.5+ with maven or forgot to download the org.reactivestreams:reactivestreams dependency of RxJava 2.

Comment: Thanks, no I believe I have it set up correctly, all I need is the 2.0.5 dependency, correct? I originally had the IntelliJ project pointing to rxjava io.reactivex
rxjava 1.2.5 and it was working fine. Then I switched to rxjava2 2.0.5, did a clean install and a rebuild project just to make sure, and I checked the libraries, and everything is correct. But IntelliJ is loading up the wrong class. Building from the command line worked fine. So I copied everything to a new project and it worked fine as well. Prob some small bug. They are usually very good about swatting these

Comment: By the way, is it possible to do this using an Observable, if I am willing to forfeit the back pressure? Or is that a nonsensical use case?

Comment: All base types have `create()`.